# how to give current user site administrator rights programmatically

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

We want to give user site administrator rights in page load and remove it in finally block.
We are using sharepoint 2007,What is the way to implement it.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of temporarily granting access to a user, I would recommend instantiating the [SPSite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms436101%28v=office.12%29.aspx) with [SystemAccount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsite.systemaccount%28v=office.12%29.aspx):

```
SPSite site = web.Site;
Guid id = web.ID;
SPUtility.ValidateFormDigest();
using (SPSite systemSite = new SPSite(site.ID, site.SystemAccount.UserToken))
{
    using (SPWeb systemWeb = systemSite.OpenWeb(id))
    {
        // perform as site administrator
    }
}
```

Comment: does not contain a definition for 'Web'
getting above compilation error to below line
SPSite site = this.Web.Site;

thanks a lot for taking time for me :)

Comment: I changed the code so that the original SPWeb is a variable rather than a property. One way or another, you will need an SPWeb instance to determine your context.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend running under elevated privileges in your code.  This will give your code that is executed higher permissions temporarily.  Make sure you open your site, web and list objects are opened under this delegate.  See MSDN [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsecurity.runwithelevatedprivileges.aspx) and sample below.

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{
   using (SPSite site = new SPSite(web.Site.ID))
   {
     // implementation details omitted
   }
})
```